# How to notify without websocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I want to integrate a simple notification system in my react application. I want to notify for example:
- new post (when the user post the system need time to transcode the media attached and the publication)
- missing settings (the user need to compile some information)
- interesting posts etc..

There is a simple way to add a websocket, like socket.io, to a reactjs app with an aws lambda backend?

All the notification not need to be read in real time, maybe an ajax call every 2 minutes can solve my problem, but, in this case, someone can help me avoid ajax call if the app isn't used(like if the app remain opened in a foreground tab...)

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.liveUpdate()
    setInterval(this.liveUpdate, 120000);
}

liveUpdate() {
    axios.get(endpoint.posts+'/live/', cfg)
        .then(res => {
            // ...
        });
}
```

This code is in the footer component, the call happen every 120 seconds, but the call will still happen also if a user leave the application opened in the browser and not use it, this on a lambda backend mean a waste of money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 main ways of notifying that I can think of at the moment...

1. Long polling (using ajax etc)
2. Websocket
3. Push Notification

Push (though) requires permission from the user

Comment: Thank You. Long polling I think is the better choice in my case. Just I need to stop the Ajax request in case of long inactivity. I’m still looking for a solution